# What kind of data is this, and how do I turn it to human readable form with python?

Tags: python, hex, byte, raw-data

I'm pulling data out from DA-14585 IoT device. I'm getting a report from the temperature sensor which is as follows:

`a50f060203d10900000b020390290000`

Reading [the documentation](https://www.dialog-semiconductor.com/sites/default/files/um-b-101_da14585_iot_multi_sensor_development_kit_developer_guide_rev1.1.pdf#table12) (search for table 12) tells me that

`a5` is preamble

`0f` is timestamp

`06` is the sensor id (temperature)

`02` is the sensor state (always 2)

`03` is the sensor value (always 3)

`d10900000b020390290000` is the actual sensor data, which is listed as "Val32".

Mainly I'm wondering, what format is this data in, and how would one go with turning this into a human readable form? Same goes for the timestamp, which is 0f.

I'm mainly working with Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Val32` is a 32-bit integer (little-endian by the look of things).  In your example, `d1090000`.  What follows thereafter is a subsequent message which will need to be decoded separately (it has the same format and is of type `GAS_REPORT_ID`).

Since `0x000009d1 = 2513`, if I were to guess I'd say this is in hundredths of degrees C, i.e. `25.13C` (assuming this is ambient temperature and not, say, a reading from an oven).  Please don't rely on my guesswork though and read the relevant specs. :)

You could use the [`struct`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) module to unpack the binary data in Python.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what pointed me to the right direction. 25,13 degrees celcius is indeed the reading I'm supposed to get.